# The use of a full stop at the end of incomplete sentence fragment?

Tags: punctuation

> Fifty one thousand square miles area.
>   A hundred and fifty six million people.
>   A thousand dollars or less average annual earning per person.

Is it ok to use these full stops at the end of these sentence fragments?

Comment: At the end of a sentence fragment? Yes.

Comment: Please note that in some formal contexts, sentence fragments—whether neatly parceled out with full stops or bundled with less severe punctuation (such as commas or semicolons)—may be deemed inappropriate by the publisher, professor, or other reader.

Comment: @SvenYargs Yes, it is helpful to point that out. Thanks for doing so. However, in this particular instance, this sounds more like the introduction to some kind of call-to-action (eg to donate to a non-profit or raise awareness and sympathy for the dispossessed), so I imagine the sentence fragments are ok here.

Comment: Alternatively, you could inflate the full stop, move it to the front of the fragment, and call it a bullet point. :)

Comment: If you're using staccato running text (as here), full stops are needed, to aid reading and mark the abrupt stops. If you're using individual phrases as labels, no. Look up "crots Nordquist" and  "sentence fragments Nordquist" on the internet, and "crots" and "sentence fragments" here.

Comment: It's a definite maybe.  Context is important:  Why do  these fragments exist?  It gets especially messy with bullet lists and the like.

Comment: What do you propose one uses after them?

Answer (score 0):

Open up pretty much any children's picture book these days and you'll see plenty of sentence fragments with periods. Even the bestsellers. However, unless you're writing a headline, I'd be very cautious. Somebody without a ton of exposure, say a boss reading a resume, might simply be pur off by your lack of "grammar."

Answer (score -1):

Sentence fragments are grammatically incorrect, but it would be wrong to tell you not to use them. There are times when they are a good idea, for example fiction writers can use sentence fragments quite usefully to communicate tone, intensity, emphasis etc. However, it would be best to stay away from them in formal writing.

Comment: I think sentence fragments are more a matter of style than grammar, though this of course depends on the definition of grammar.

Comment: I believe your first sentence to be a contradiction in terms. Either they're incorrect and shouldn't be used, or the people insisting they're always incorrect are wrong. I'd say that many if not most people nowadays see them as powerful and elegant dramatic devices if used wisely. // The question was about punctuation.

Comment: Sentence fragments, by definition, do not "parse" as grammatical English sentences.  This is not to say that they are "incorrect", however, as there are many contexts where they are perfectly valid.  A rigid adherence to some grammar standard does not guarantee valid English, nor does a failure to adhere to the standard necessarily make a sequence of words invalid English.